# Using javascript to add text text to HTML DOM and insert line breaks in between

Tags: javascript

I want all the stings of this code on separate lines, but it all goes on one line.
I have already tries `\r` and `\n`
 here are the first few lines:

```
 document.write("you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure");
 document.write("be warned, the caverns are always changing");
 document.write("...");
```

Comment: Have you tried `<br />`? (If the document is XHTML.)

Comment: If you are outputting HTML, you need `<br>`

Comment: By the way - is this going to be a remake of the classic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write` produces HTML. Whitespace is condensed in HTML, so if you need a linebreak, you'll need to use a `<br>` element.

```
document.write("you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure<br>");
document.write("be warned, the caverns are always changing<br>");
document.write("...<br>");
```

Also, you don't need to break the `document.write` string into multiple calls:

```
document.write('you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure<br>be warned, the caverns are always changing<br>...');
```

Generally speaking, `document.write` should be discouraged because it will rewrite the entire page if called after the document is closed to writing. Typically these sorts of changes are done through DOM nodes:

```
document.body.innerHTML = 'you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure<br>be warned, the caverns are always changing<br>...';
```

Alternatively, if you need to guarantee formatting of text, you could use a `<pre>` element (or CSS with `white-space: pre`). Preformatted text allows newlines and multiple spaces to be respected:

```
<pre>you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure
be warned, the caverns are always changing
...</pre>
```

Answer (score 10):

\r and \n are for line breaks in the document, which doesn't matter as far as what is rendered (html) unless you're within a `<pre>` tag or using the css property `whitespace` to have the document whitespace rendered. In html a line break is `<br>`.

While the `<br>` tag is sometimes useful, don't use it without reason. For example, if you want to split up two paragraghs, you would have markup like this:

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
```

To make a space in between them, you could use css style:

```
p {
  display: block;
  margin-botton: 20px;
}
```

In this case, you should **NOT** use the `<br>` tag like this:

```
<p>This is paragraph 1.</p>
<br>
<p>This is paragraph 2.</p>
```

Also note that `document.write` is a dangerous practice and is almost never necessary. Rather than using document.write, you can use javascript to create/manipulate elements like this:

```
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = 'This is paragraph 1.';
document.body.appendChild(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must do it using document, use document.writeln instead of document.write

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use HTML tags:

```
document.write("<p>you are an explorer, entering a dragons cavern in hopes of treasure</p>");
document.write("<p>be warned, the caverns are always changing</p>");
document.write("<p>...</p>");
```

Comment: Please do not encourage the use of `document.write` in inappropriate cases like this. Also, the html tags themselves don't determine spacing. That would be up to the css styles applied to them.

Answer (score 0):

when using `document.write();` you need to realize that this is HTML that it is producing, therefore, you should use `<br>` to create the desired result.  Besides, this method is not really highly favored.